# Number of ways to arrange $n$ integers from $1$ to $n$ such that $k-1$ or $k-2$ is to the left of $k$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

How can I find the number of ways to arrange $n$ integers in a line satisfying the following conditions:

I. The first number in the line is $1$.
II. $\forall k = 2..n $ in the line, there must exist at least the number $k-1$ or $k-2$ to the left of it.

For example with $n=5$, the sequence $(1,3,5,4,2)$ satisfies the above conditions, whereas $(1,2,5,3,4)$ does not.

My attempt:

We define $a_n$ the number of arrangements satisfy the above conditions. A bit of brute-force yields $a_1 =1, a_2=1, a_3=2, a_4=4, a_5=10$. I noticed that $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + na_n$, but was unable to prove it.

I let $a_n = b_n + c_n$ where $b_n$ is the number of arrangements such that $n-2$ is to the left of $n$ and $n-1$, $c_n$ is the number of arrangements such that $n-1$ is to the left of $n$ and $n-2$ (it is obvious that $n$ cannot be to the left of both $n-1$ and $n-2$). But it was too hard to find the recurrence relations of the two sequence since I thought I had to find the exact position of $n-1$ and $n$ in every arrangement in order to find the number ways to put $n+1$ in so I'm clueless now.

Comment: If your $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + na_n$ is correct then this is [OEIS A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085) offset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly $1$ must be at the first position. On the second position, we can have either $2$ or $3$.

If we have $2$ on second position, we need to arrange $2,3, \ldots ,n-1,n$ like we would do for $1,2, \ldots ,n-2,n-1$, therefore with $a_{n-1}$ possible arrangements.

If we have $3$ on second position, consider removing $2$ from the permutation. The remaining $3,4, \ldots ,n-1,n$ can be arranged like we would do for $1,2, \ldots ,n-3,n-2$, therefore with $a_{n-2}$ possible arrangements. We can remove $2$ because $4$ has already $3$ satisfying the condition "$k-1$ to the left of $k$", and $5, \ldots ,n \gt 2+2$, therefore the position of $2$ is not relevant for the arrangement of the other values. After that, $2$ can be inserted in every place, except the first position of the subsequence, therefore in $n-2$ places.

Putting this altogether we have your recurrence:

$$a_n = a_{n-1}+(n-2)a_{n-2}$$